# Joomla - href to component controller in admin

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am having below href , unable to call test function in scholarship(component) controller,this href redirects to same page

http://192.168.1.9/joomla2/administrator/index.php?option=com_scholarships&task=scholarships/test

Comment: The link you've provided doesn't even work. In addition to that, please could you be a little more specific as to what your issue is, else the question will most likely be closed

Answer (score 3):

The controller function test is called like this:
index.php?option=com_scholarships&task=**scholarships.test**

Answer (score -1):

Joomla mostly works with POST form actions. For instance, task buttons have a tiny JavaScript to submit a POST. Addtionally , most forms also submit a token for security.

To sum up, you cannot craft an Url to test a controller. At least, you have to define an action button in the toolbar.